# This C program to sort the students array size 5 based on the students rank. Those ranking need to be sorted by selection and insertion sorting method

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

**These Warning Pops When Program Compiles**

[Warnings List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5zNp.png)

```
C:\MinGW\Bimsara\Third Semester\DTS\Week7>gcc -o test test.c
test.c: In function 'main':

test.c:31:27: warning: passing argument 1 of 'selectionSortStudents' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     selectionSortStudents(info, 5);
                       ^~~~
test.c:14:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'struct Student *'
 void selectionSortStudents(int info[5], int count);

test.c:35:27: warning: passing argument 1 of 'insertionSortStudents' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     insertionSortStudents(info, 5);
                       ^~~~
test.c:15:6: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'struct Student *'


void insertionSortStudents(int info[5], int count);
```

**Program**
Structure

```
struct Student
{
    char Name[100];
    int Rank;
};
```

struct Student info[5];
Main Function

This is how I passed parameters in main function

```
    selectionSortStudents(info, 5);

    insertionSortStudents(info, 5);
```

Function used to selection sort

```
void selectionSortStudents(int info[5], int count)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
    {
        int j, min, temp;
        min = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
        {
            if (info[j] < info[min])
                min = j;
        }
        temp == info[i];
        info[i] = info[min];
        info[min] == temp;
    }
}
```

Function used to insertion sort

```
void insertionSortStudents(int info[5], int count)
{
    int i, j, index;
    for (i = 1; i < count; i++)
    {
        index = info[i];
        for (j = i; j > 0 && info[j - 1] > index; j--)
            info[j] = info[j - 1];
        info[j] = index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add warnings output as text and not a link to an image. And please ask a specific question - what is it you don't understand or need help with?

Comment: Review `temp == info[i];`.  Tip: enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: @kaylum Thank you for responding. I added a screenshot of warnings and also as a text that display while compiling the program. I need to get rid of those warnings. Thank You

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thank you. Noted and done.

Comment: "I need to get rid of those warnings" is not a question. What do you not understand about `expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'struct Student *'`? If you tell us we can explain more but that seems fairly self explanatory.

Comment: @kaylum When the code compiles, name of the highest rank student doesn't print. Sorting works fine. I need to know what are the reason for those warnings and how to remove them.

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking you: What is stopping you from fixing the warnings? What is it about this that is unclear to you: `expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'struct Student *'`? The function's first arg is declared to be `int info[5]` which is of type `int *`. But you pass it `info` which is of type `struct Student *`. So either the function definition needs to change or the caller needs to pas in something different.

Comment: To be clear: `temp == info[i];` is a comparison, not an assignment.  Enable more warnings.